# How to check if all the members of a list lies in specific ranges based on another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, operators

There are two lists as follows:

```
lista = {i, j, k};
listb = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

If `i` in `{1, 2}` (namely, $ 1 \leq i \leq 2 $, where `1` and `2` come from the first item of `listb`), `j` in `{3, 4}`, and `k` in `{5, 6}`, it will give `True`. If only one condition is not met, it will give `False`. How to make it come true? It's best to achieve the function in one line. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Apply[And] @* MapThread[Between] @* List;

f0[lista, listb]
```

> ```
> 1 <= i && i <= 2 && 3 <= j && j <= 4 && 5 <= k && k <= 6
> ```

```
f0[ {1, 3, 5}, listb]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
f0[ {1, 3, 7}, listb]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Also

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6]

f1 = And @@ Between @@@ Transpose[{##}] &;

f2 = And @@ MapThread[Between] @ {##} &;

f3 = And @@ LessEqual @@@ MapThread[Riffle] @ {#2, #} &;

f4 = And @@ MapThread[#2 @ # &]@ {#, Between /@ #2}&;

f5 = And @@ MapThread[Apply[LessEqual] @* Riffle] @ {#2, #} &;

f6 = And @@ MapThread[IntervalMemberQ] @ {Interval /@ #2, #} &;
```

Comment: In fact, the `lista` is very large, `lista = {{i1, j1, k1},{i2, j2, k2},{i3, j3, k3}.......{in, jn, kn}}`, I want to take `listb` as a filter to sieve the unwanted data out of the `lista`. For simplification, I only take a item from `lista`. Your solution is so perfect that it surprises me，leaving endless aftertaste.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 2; j = 3; k = 4;
lista = {i, j, k}
listb = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

MapThread[MemberQ[#1, #2] &, {listb, lista}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you want `<=i<=` then

```
MapThread[If[First@#1 <= #2 <= Last@#1, True, False] &, {listb, lista}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[i, j, k];
i = 2; j = 9; k = 4;
lista = {i, j, k}
listb = {{1, 7}, {3, 11}, {5, 6}}

MapThread[If[First@#1 <= #2 <= Last@#1, True, False] &, {listb, lista}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your attention